# How to set the background color in a LineChart (Google visualization) in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, css, google-visualization, linechart

Ok, this sounds like a stupid question. And probably is... sorry if so, but I could not find the answer.

I have a `LineChart`, and want to set it with black semi transparent background. The WHOLE thing, not just the frame around the chart: I don't want to see any frame.

In Chrome and Firefox this looks great. However, in Android it looks awful, with the chart WHITE (?) and the background black, and I cannot changed it! I've played for a long time with `backgroundColor`, `backgroundColor.fill`, `colors`, CSS, without success. I even tried with both:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
```

and

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['corechart']});
```

Is this an Android webview bug or what??

This is my code. First, the CSS of the `div` containing the chart, and then the `LineChart` options:

CSS:

```
  #elevation_chart {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
```

Javascript:

```
var option = {
  legend: 'none',
  height: 100,
  width: 200,
  curveType:'function',
  lineWidth: 2,
  colors: ["#FFFF00"],
  chartArea: {left: 35, width: 160, height: 90 },
  vAxis: {
    gridlines: {color: '#FFF', count: 8},
    baselineColor: 'black',
    textStyle: { color: '#FFF', bold: true },
  },
  backgroundColor: '#000',
  intervals: { 'style':'line' }, // Use line intervals.
  focusTarget: 'category',
  tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },
  }
```

Thanks!

L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the `backgroundColor` to `transparent`:

http://jsfiddle.net/63Phz/

Comment: Indeed!! However, I had to change the CSS in the HTML too: the `opacity` option messes up the chart in Android, both in `webview` and in browser (Dolphin), certainly a bug. So, besides `backgroundColor: 'transparent'` in the javascript `LineChart` option, I deleted the `opacity` CSS option and added `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)`. Thanks a LOT!